# Elastic delete/expire indexes after months

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a strange problem with elastic search. Basically with an application we generate indexes incrementally (for each new document inserted) but  in about 2 months  they get deleted completely.  I can't find anything about the fact that every time the indices "expire". can you tell me something about it? Did someone using elastic search have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is nothing built into Elasticsearch that would do that (though that will change soon with the Index Lifecycle Manager).

Normally it's:

- https://github.com/elastic/curator running somewhere and cleaning up.
- You have a cron job (or something similar) that runs a `curl -XDELETE ...` on indices that are older than a specific amount of time.
- Your own application is doing it.